# Spring - AuthenticationEntryPoint is called after login

Tags: spring, spring-security

In my Spring app, I would like to return 401 status if user is not logged in. I created a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` which does the thing:

```
@Component( "restAuthenticationEntryPoint" )
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint
        implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized" );
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

The problem is that `commence()` is called always, even after successful authentication. Why is that?

Comment: I doubt it. An `AuthenticationEntryPoint` is only called, if you have not the neccessary role. Could you add the Spring Secruity logs with `DEBUG` enabled in your log configuration?

Comment: I see no authentication type in your configuration. I guess, you are not logged in at all.

Comment: Note shortcut authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))